# Pandas creating a conditional column based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df's

df1:

```
index    text
1        string1
2        string2
3        string3
4        a
5        string5
6        a
```

df2:

```
index    text
4        string4
6        string6
```

How can I replace the text 'a' in df1 with the values found in df2 based on the index, so that it shows as below.

df3:

```
index    text
1        string1
2        string2
3        string3
4        string4
5        string5
6        string6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas-dataframe-update) as:

```
df1.set_index('index',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('index',inplace=True)
df1.update(df2) #df1 is changed
```

Or

```
df1.loc[df2.index,'text'] = df2['text'] #df1 is changed
```

Or The output to be in df3 then

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3.update(df2) #df3 is changed
```

All of them produces:

```
       text
index   
1   string1
2   string2
3   string3
4   string4
5   string5
6   string6
```

Comment: Please update your answer, it should be `df1.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)` and `df2.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)` in order to get the desired output shown.

Comment: @Nand Checked in pandas `0.23.4` `drop=True` is not needed.

Comment: wonderful!, this is exactly what i needed,had to do a simple column name change for it to work in my case

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
pd.merge(df1[[]], df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

or

```
df2.loc[df1.index]
```

Comment: merge and loc added more columns than i needed, thanks, but update() did the trick for me